# Python: Is it possible to compare unicode strings by the visible outcome

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

if i have Strings with arabic and latin letters mixed, the outcome can be strange.

e.g. a String can look like this:
(2)‏بسك‏ويت 
or like this: 
‏(2)‏بسك‏ويت

and the only difference is a right-to-left mark (which is a invisible unicode character U+200F) in the second one. 
However it wouldn't make any difference if there is only one right-to-left-mark or if there are multiple. 
There could also be the normal right-to-left or a embedded right to left (U+200F or U+202B)

when i compare two string, i only know if they are equal.
Is there also a possibility to know if the visible outcome would be the same even if the strings are not the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it could be difficult, and it depends exactly on what text do you have.

The module `unicodedata` will provide you the data. Personally, I would start with a normalization, E.g. with `NFKC` or `NFC`, depending on your inputs.

```
 s = unicodedata.normalize(form, s)
```

Then I would filter our the unneeded characters.

```
 s = [c for c in s if not unicodedata.category(c).startswith('C')]
```

You will find the possible *General Category* in http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-6.html#Property_Values .
The categories which start with C are *control/Formatting*.
But you may need to include also other space characters, depending on use case.
Maybe you need also to do an other "normalization", merging all spaces into one U+0020.

It is very difficult to generalize (but the first normalization), because every unicode code point could have some semantic significance.
So you should check what you can discard and what you must maintain.